# Split an iterator by a predicate

Tags: scala, iterator

I need a method that can split `Iterator[Char]` into lines (separated by `\n` and `\r`)

For that, I wrote a general method that gets an iterator and a predicate and will split the iterator every time the predicate is true. 
This is similar to `span`, but will split every time the predicate is true, not only the first time

this is my implementation:

```
def iterativeSplit[T](iterO: Iterator[T])(breakOn: T => Boolean): Iterator[List[T]] = 
 new Iterator[List[T]] {
  private var iter = iterO
  def hasNext = iter.hasNext

  def next = {
    val (i1,i2) = iter.span(el => !breakOn(el))
    val cur = i1.toList
    iter = i2.dropWhile(breakOn)
    cur
  }
}.withFilter(l => l.nonEmpty)
```

and it works well on small inputs, but on larges inputs, this runs very slow, and sometimes I get stack overflow exception

here is the code that recreates the issue:

```
val iter = ("aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccc\r\n" * 10000).iterator
iterativeSplit(iter)(c => c == '\r' || c == '\n').length
```

the stack trace during the run is:

```
... 
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:615)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$18.hasNext(Iterator.scala:591)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:615)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$18.hasNext(Iterator.scala:591)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:615)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$18.hasNext(Iterator.scala:591)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.hasNext(Iterator.scala:847)
...
```

looking at the source code (I'm using scala 2.10.4)
line 591 is the `hasNext` of the second iterator from the `span`, and line 651 is the `hasNext` in the iterator from `dropWhile`

I guess I'm using those 2 iterators incorrectly, but I can't see why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code as follows, which seems to solve the problem:

```
  def iterativeSplit2[T](iter: Iterator[T])(breakOn: T => Boolean): Iterator[List[T]] =
    new Iterator[List[T]] {
      def hasNext = iter.hasNext

      def next = {
        val cur = iter.takeWhile(!breakOn(_)).toList
        iter.dropWhile(breakOn)
        cur
      }
    }.withFilter(l => l.nonEmpty)
```

Rather than using `span` (so you need to replace `iter` on each call to `next`), simply use `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` on the original `iter`.  Then there's no need for the `var`.

I think the cause of your original stack overflow is that repeatedly calling `span` creates a long chain of `Iterator`s, each of whose `hasNext` methods calls the `hasNext` of its parent `Iterator`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala) for `Iterator`, you can see that each `span` creates new Iterators that forward calls to `hasNext` to the original iterator (via a `BufferedIterator`, which increases the call stack even further).

**Update** having consulted the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator) it seems that, although my solution above appears to work, it is not recommended - see particularly:

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise,
>   one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it.
>   [...] Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterator as well.

which applies to `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` (and `span`), but not `next` or `hasNext`.

It's possible to use `span` as in your original solution, but using streams rather than iterators, and recursion:

```
  def split3[T](s: Stream[T])(breakOn: T => Boolean): Stream[List[T]] = s match {
    case Stream.Empty => Stream.empty
    case s => {
      val (a, b) = s.span(!breakOn(_))
      a.toList #:: split3(b.dropWhile(breakOn))(breakOn)
    }
  }
```

But the performance is pretty terrible. I'm sure there must be a better way...

**Update 2:** Here is a very imperative solution that has better performance:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

  def iterativeSplit4[T](iter: Iterator[T])(breakOn: T => Boolean): Iterator[List[T]] =
    new Iterator[List[T]] {
      val word = new ListBuffer[T]
      def hasNext() = iter.hasNext

      def next = {
        var looking = true
        while (looking) {
          val c = iter.next
          if (breakOn(c)) looking = false
          else word += c
        }
        val w = word.toList
        word.clear()
        w
      }
    }.withFilter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: Nicely done, thanks. And now the `dropWhile` is also unneeded since the filter will take care of the breaking elements.

Comment: I have updated my answer, since I realized that my original solution uses techniques that are strongly discouraged in the documentation.

Comment: This is great, thank you! To prevent an error when using `toList` on the split iterator, I added `while (looking && iter.hasNext)`